# DDMathParser & iOS7/XCode Compatibility

Tags: ios, ddmathparser

I added [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) as a submodule in my Git repository, and after running it, the code only seems to work with OS X. Right away it gives me the following error in `DemoController.h`, etc.:

`'Cocoa/Cocoa.h' file not found`

Can DDMathParser work with a mobile device using iOS7? If so, it isn't clear to me how to accomplish this. My google search online suggests that Cocoa is not possible with iOS. I *was* able to get it working with Mac OS X - how can I do the same for iOS with my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DDMathParser author here. You've copied over more than you need. As the name implies, `DemoController` is part of a demo showing how the parser works. You shouldn't be including it in your app.

Comment: Well that was a careless mistake on my part. It would be nice, however, if I could delete the unnecessary files; if I do so, will a submodule update re-download them?

Comment: @Biff I recommend [reading the wiki page on integrating `DDMathParser`](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Adding-DDMathParser-to-your-project). I think a `git submodule update` should bring it all back, but I'd have to try it to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely works with iOS 7.  I copied it into my Xcode project folder and it parses like a champ.  Can you try that first, then work on Git?